# Outlook 365 add-in, call a SOAP web service and move email to folder

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm developing a simple outlook add-in that should run on the web version of outlook 365. This add-in should call an external web service and move the email to a folder which more likely won't be a well-known folder.

I am new to this kind of development, so I've been reading information and trying samples out for days but I am still confused on which way to go. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and trying to avoid Yeoman.

Since I am on a very early stage and I can't seem to find definitive info, I would very much appreciate if you could point me in the right direction with these:

1. I need to create an Outlook web add-in. Don't I?
2. To call a web service that is on a different domain, I need to enable CORS on the service.
   After reading the following articles I still have not been able to make it work.
   [Outlook add-in: Make an Exchange Web Service request from Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/outlook-add-in-javascript-makeewsrequest/outlook-add-in-make-an-exchange-web-service-request-from-outlook/)
   [Create a web service for an app for Office using the ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/officeapps/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api)

   I was able to run the EWS sample but I could not make it work to call an external WS that's when I found out I needed to enable CORS, is there a free WS with CORS enabled I could use to test and learn?. Also I don't know if I should use EWS, I'm afraid it could be deprecated soon.
3. To move the email to another folder I need to use... EWS? MS Graph?
   If it is Graph, please point me to a demo or something that would help me understand how to build an outlook add in using graph, I've been checking out [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) but I wouldn't know how to implement a move to folder call.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Building an Outlook Web Addin today would enable the addin for all platforms and not just web. Any specific reason you are looking to enable this add-in only for Web clients?  Also, is there a reason you want the external service to do the move operation? Why not have the web add-in itself call into Graph/Rest endpoint to do the move of the email? Yeoman generator is the most simplistic way to onboard to creating an addin, any specific reason you're steering away from it

Comment: Thank you for replying @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT! I don't mind the add-in being available to other platforms, the add-in will be available for an org internally and they only use the web clients. I am absolutely new to the whole add-in world and I can't seem to find clear information on what would be the right path to follow. As for the reason why I'm trying to move the email from an external call, ignorance, those are the examples I've found and I am testing out how I could do it but if you could point me where to look I would be grateful.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT As for Yeoman, we have visual studio as our main tool for developing, I thought this would have taken less time and not knowing about the learning curve of another tool made me try to go for the well-known. But I'm open to hear suggestions if it's really easy to learn and be productive in little to no time.

Comment: In order to perform the move email action, you can refer to the EWS operations documentation under "MoveItem" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services#ews-operations-that-add-ins-support
As for starting add-in development, simple instructions to get started with Yeoman can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator
Additionally, you might also find it helpful to try and test out code snippets with the Script Lab add-in in the add-ins AppStore.